# ExtJS 4.1 - Disappearing selection when editing cell (ComboBox editor)

Tags: javascript, gridview, checkbox, extjs4.1

I have GridPanel with 2 columns :

1. Type : string
2. Details : combo

I added CheckBox selection model and I have a little problem.

When I select couple rows and want to edit Details column in some of the selected row or even not-selected, selection disappears. Only edited row remain selected.
I can't find any solution for this. Can anyone help me ?

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/papcio28/fkJT3/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the editing model and checkbox selection model and not compatible.  The technical reason for this is that the checkbox model uses the rowselection model on the grid and grideditor uses cellselection model on the grid.  I don't think that Extjs is compatible with your requirements here since the cell selection model is necessary for the grid to know where to put an editor and row selection model is necessary for you to visually see the selection when using checkbox selection model.  In your example it sounds like it choses the row selection model, which means it selects the row when you start editing because the row has to be selected for it to know where to the put the editor.

My suggestion for you is to use checkcolumn plugin and fake the rows being selected by using a  renderer on every column that changes the background to the selected color when the value for your checkcolumn is true, this way it will look like a row selection model, but not actually be one.